# Magento - After user login it gets redirected to checkout

Tags: magento, authentication, checkout, account

Ok. The problem is following. If I add an item to cart like anonymus user, and then go to log in section I'm getting redirected to checkout login page insteas to uaer account page. Even if I enter wrong usernam and password I will be redirected to checkout page where dit will display that entered username and pass are incorrect. Where should I look. Thanks
Btw it is magento ee 1.14.